# Firebase tem limite de armazenamento e download de arquivos?

Tags: firebase

Estou estudando armazenar arquivos no Firebase para que os usuários de meu aplicativo possam baixá-los.

Alguém saberia me dizer se há limite de armazenamento e download de arquivos armazenados no Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendo na própria documentação https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=pt-br

Tem limites sim, no plano gratuito 5gb de storage e 1gb de downloads diários.

Comment: Obrigado pela info.

Comment: Marca como resolvido ai

Comment: Fui orientado que não é necessário colocar como resolvido. Mas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Se não é necessario marcar como resolvido seria melhor excluir essa pergunta

Comment: @Henqsan porque não é necessário? Você marca se resolveu seu problema caso contrário não marca, seja lá quem te orientou fez errado ou você entendeu errado. LEIA: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635) !

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento usuário novo, aparece faz uma pergunta e some só pode kkk

Comment: A orientação foi dada nesse tópico:  (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/ler-linha-txt-e-incluir)

Comment: @Henqsan você entendeu totalmente errado, lá a orientação do Articuno (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/ler-linha-txt-e-incluir#comment374077_180451) é pra não escrever a palavra "Resolvido" no título da pergunta. Tenha atenção as orientações para não se confundir. Não é necessário ***"escrever"*** [Resolvido] porque não somos um fórum, o site tem a opção de marcar a resposta que resolveu o vosso problema. Compreende?

Comment: Agora entendi. Já marquei a resposta que me ajudou. Espero que todos fiquem felizes 